# I need guidance on jQuery Search input

Tags: jquery, search, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a search field on my page to search the whole page. I am referencing

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/search/index.html

and i cant grasp this. Can someone who knows how to use this please explain how i can use search input on my mobile app.

not sure how to set up the js method to fire off the search etc..

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//wait for our page to be created by jQuery Mobile
$(document).delegate('#page-id', 'pageinit', function () {

    //cache the elements we want to show/hide based on the search input
    var $filterDivs = $('.filter-div');

    //bind an event handler to the search input for when it's value changes
    $('#search').bind('keyup change', function () {

        //if the value of the input is nothing, then show all the elements
        if (this.value == '') {
            $filterDivs.slideDown(500);

        //otherwise find only the elements that match what's in the search input
        } else {

            //create a regular expression based on the value of the search input
            var regxp = new RegExp(this.value),

                //get only the elements that match the search term(s)
                $show = $filterDivs.filter(function () {
                    return ($(this).attr('data-filter').search(regxp) > -1);
                });

            //hide the elements that do not match
            $filterDivs.not($show).slideUp(500);

            //and show the elements that do match
            $show.slideDown(500);
        }
    });
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/cZW5r/1/

Here is the basic HTML structure this uses:

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="search">Search Input:</label>
        <input type="search" name="password" id="search" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="filter-div" data-filter="one">1</div>
    <div class="filter-div" data-filter="two">2</div>
    <div class="filter-div" data-filter="three">3</div>
    <div class="filter-div" data-filter="four">4</div>
    <div class="filter-div" data-filter="five">5</div>
```

Notice the `data-filter` attributes, these are the attributes that are checked against the search term(s).

Answer (score 1):

That link is only showing you how to setup the search input text box. Doing the actual search is something you would need to program yourself. There isn't really a JavaScript solution to search every page of your site. You could setup a JavaScript solution to search a single page of your site, but that probably isn't what you want to do.

You might want to take a look at some of these links to see search solutions:

[How to setup a simple site search for a simple website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285763/how-to-setup-a-simple-site-search-for-a-simple-website)

[Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/)